# Match table id with the object key?

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-objects

I have table with id's on each table cell. Each id have matching key in Javascript object. Ajax call will return Object with values. I want to loop through the table and assign value to each table cell if the key is matching cell id. Here is example:

HTML Table:

```
<table class="tblData">
    <tr>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <td id="st_lname"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <td id="st_fname"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>DOB</th>
        <td id="st_dob"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Javascript:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'Components/getRecords.cfc?method='+getMethod,
    data: {'userID':userID},
    dataType: 'json'
}).done(function(obj){
    if(obj.STATUS == 200){
        //Here I can access my obj.DATA values and get the key for each value
        $('.tblData table tr td').each(function(){
            $(this).attr('id').toUpperCase();
        });

        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
    alert(errorThrown);
});
```

Here is how my object looks after I receive response from the server:

```
{"STATUS":200,"DATA":{"ST_DOB":"03/16/2010","ST_FNAME":"John","ST_LNAME":"Miller"}}
```

After I get successful return I want to loop through table as I mentioned above and find matching key in the object for each table cell id and assign the value to that cell. If anyone can help please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: is this a bug? or do you want someone to write the solution for you?

Comment: I'm trying to find the best way to find matching id using object key. I don't need someone to write solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Your selector is not correct. It should be `.tblData tr td`. You can assign the value using jQuery's [text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-text) method

```js
var res = {
  "STATUS": 200,
  "DATA": {
    "ST_DOB": "03/16/2010",
    "ST_FNAME": "John",
    "ST_LNAME": "Miller"
  }
};

$('.tblData tr td').each(function(i, ele) {
  var id = $(ele).attr('id').toUpperCase();
  var value = res.DATA[id];
  if (value) {
    $(ele).text(value);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="tblData">
  <tr>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <td id="st_lname"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <td id="st_fname"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>DOB</th>
    <td id="st_dob"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```